# python networkx algorithm to get paths with condition as product of edge weight

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

I have a networkx directed graph with edge weights as probabilities. I want all the paths between two nodes such that the product of the edge weights is above a threshold. 
For example A->B->C->D could be 0.9*0.9*0.1 = 0.081 and 0.081 > 0.5 so accept the path.
All the path algorithms have to do with summing the weights (shortest path). Is there a way to use product of edges as a condition ?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, list(YourGraph.edges_iter(data='weight', default=1)))
```

This will multiply all of the edge weights in the graph.